# Field updates for a second then disapears

Tags: javascript

so i made a field status as p paragraph, and it supposed to be able to hold a value after button click but it only appears momentary and disappears

the library js just has the array required to fill in the data needed

```
<script src="library.js"></script>
<b id="chakra"></b>
<div id="planet"></div>
<script>    
    var index = setChakra(0);
    var planetConection = "";

    function setChakra(index){
        document.getElementById("chakra").innerHTML = chakra[index];
        while (index < chakra.length){
            getPlanets(index);
            if (index < chakra.length-1) index++;
            else index = 0;
            break;
        }
        return index;
    }   

    function getPlanets(chakra){
        var planetIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("planet").innerHTML = "";
        while( planetIndex < chakraPlanets[chakra].length){
                document.getElementById("planet").innerHTML = document.getElementById("planet").innerHTML + planetDesc[chakraPlanets[chakra][planetIndex]] +
                "<form>" +
                    "<input id=\"planetStatus" + planetIndex + "\" type=\"text\" name=\"plntStat\">" +
                    "<button onclick=\"getPlanetConection(" + planetIndex + ")\">Click Me!</button>" +
                "</form>" +
                "<p id=\"status\"></p>";
                planetIndex++;
            }
    }

    function getPlanetConection(planetIndex){
        planetConection = document.getElementById("planetStatus" + planetIndex).value;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = planetConection;
    }   

</script>
<button onclick = "index = setChakra(index)" >Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it button is meant to be input if i am not refreshing the page

```
<script src="library.js"></script>
<b id="chakra"></b>
<div id="planet"></div>
<script>    
    var index = setChakra(0);
    var planetConection = "";

    function setChakra(index){
        document.getElementById("chakra").innerHTML = chakra[index];
        while (index < chakra.length){
            getPlanets(index);
            if (index < chakra.length-1) index++;
            else index = 0;
            break;
        }
        return index;
    }   

    function getPlanets(chakra){
        var planetIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("planet").innerHTML = "";
        while( planetIndex < chakraPlanets[chakra].length){
            document.getElementById("planet").innerHTML = document.getElementById("planet").innerHTML + planetDesc[chakraPlanets[chakra][planetIndex]] +
            "<form>" +
                "<input id=\"planetStatus" + planetIndex + "\" type=\"text\" name=\"plntStat\">" +
                "<input value=\"Click\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"getPlanetConection(" + planetIndex + ")\"/>" +
            "</form>" +
            "<p id=\"status" + planetIndex + "\"></p>";
            planetIndex++;
        }
    }

    function getPlanetConection(planetIndex){
        planetConection = document.getElementById("planetStatus" + planetIndex).value;
        document.getElementById("status" + planetIndex).innerHTML = planetConection;
    }
</script>
<button onclick = "index = setChakra(index)" >Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the page is reloading. Add a type attribute with value 'button' to your button. 
Like so:

```
<button type="button" onclick = "index = setChakra(index)" >Click Me!</button>

"<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"getPlanetConection(" + planetIndex + ")\">Click Me!</button>"
```

This is so that the button acts as a button and not a submit button.